# Access fileitem from child controller on parent controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using angular file uploader in child component and need to access the fileitem when onAfterAddingFile is fired. I have implemented binding in component. So far, I have tried this-

Childcontroller:

```
    $onInit() {

    this.feedFileInfo = 'abc';//here it is updated
    this.uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'customFilter',
        fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
            return this.queue.length < 10;
        }
    });
this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
        console.log('fileItem');
        this.feedFileInfo = 'xyz';//this value is not being updated to feedFileInfo variable and hence cannot be obtained in parent controller
        console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
    };
```

I need the updated value ie. fileitem in this variable.
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `this` from the declared `function`, not the outer one.
One classical workaround is to use:

```
var that = this;
this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function (fileItem) {
  that.feedFileInfo = 'xyz';
};
```